# How to deal with Some[String] parameters?

Tags: scala

I have the following code, but I want to make it more idiomatically correct. First of all I define three variables as `Option[String]`.

```
var p1 = None : Option[String]
var p2 = None : Option[String]
var p3 = None : Option[String]
```

Then I define these parameters using the function `getParameters()`. Basically this function simply reads parameters from text file.

```
getParameters()
//...

def getParameters(): Unit = {
    val p1 = Some(getP1())
    val p2 = Some(getP2())
    val p3 = Some(getP3())
}
```

Finally, right after `getParameters()` I run another function `getRules` that uses `p1`, `p2` and `p3`. Now it expects them to be `String` instead of `Some[String]`.

```
val df = getRules(p1,p2,p3)
```

If any of these three parameters is `None`, then the program should throw an error. I wonder if I am on the right way. What is the number of parameters is bigger, e.g. 10 or 15? What is the best short way to process these parameters?

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? Ideally you could use p1.getOrElse("") and then filter out empty strings

Comment: No, your `getParameters` does nothing at all (except maybe wasting a few milliseconds to read some bytes from the hard drive, only to throw them away). The signature with `:Unit` and bunch of local `val`s doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If getRules should throw an error, there's no point in doing `.getOrElse("")`. Just do a `.get` and let it fail.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley: I want to throw a concrete notification text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val valuesOpt = for(a <- p1; b <- p2; c <- p3) yield (a,b,c)

valuesOpt.map{
  case (a, b, c) => getRules(a, b, c)
}.getOrElse(throw new Exception("Nope"))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to unpack an Option, but in your case I think this is the easiest to read/maintain in my opinion:

```
val df = (p1, p2, p3) match {
    case (Some(x), Some(y), Some(z)) => getRules(x, y, z)
    case _ => throw new Exception("One or more values were NONE!")
}
```

*Edit: Here is a small scala fiddle to demonstrate how to use this: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/YVCYBBl/1